# Appium: Why is repeating touchAction: press&release frequently skip the input fields in a form?

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium

I created a form with several input fields within my mobile app and then I repeatly did the following:

```
touch.press(element).perform();
// driver get key board send keys
```

After repeating several times, the appium will probably skip some input field. Why would this happen? How could I prevent this?